# glmmTMB_phylo: Error in Matrix::rankMatrix(TMBStruc$data.tmb[[whichX]]) : length(d <- dim(x)) == 2 is not TRUE

Tags: r, lme4, glmmtmb, tmb

I am trying to run the following model:

```
mod1<- phylo_glmmTMB(response ~ sv1 + # sampling variables
sv2 + sv3 + sv4 + sv5 + 
sv6 + sv7 +  
(1|phylo) + (1|reference_id), #random effects
ziformula = ~ 0,
#ar1(pos + 0| group) # spatial autocorrelation structure; group is a dummy variable
phyloZ = supertreenew,
phylonm = "phylo",
family = "binomial",
data = data)
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Error in Matrix::rankMatrix(TMBStruc$data.tmb[[whichX]]) : 
length(d <- dim(x)) == 2 is not TRUE
```

This error is also occurring with other reproducible example ([`data`](https://github.com/wzmli/phyloglmm/issues/12)) that I found.

Before I run the model, I just loaded my data ([`data`](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuvDWe9kv3DqivtFut_38w8vaSoUZQ?e=kMy2RS) and [`supertree`](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuvDWe9kv3DqivslSCUUaJ6DBo0tcQ?e=pTzHVN)) and computed a Z matrix from `supertree`:

```
#Compute Z matrix
#supertreenew <- vcv.phylo(supertreenew) 
#or
supertreenew <- phylo.to.Z(supertreenew)
#enforced match between
supertreenew <- supertreenew[levels(factor(data$phylo)), ]
```

I have installed the development version via:

```
remotes::install_github("wzmli/phyloglmm/pkg")
```

But no success.

The dimension of my `supertree` are:

> [[1]]
> ... [351]
> [[2]]
> ... [645]

Any guess?

My session info:

> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)
> Matrix products: default
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
> other attached packages:
> [1] phyloglmm_0.1.0.9001 brms_2.18.0 cpp_1.0.9 performance_0.10. DHARMa_0.4.6
> [6] phytools_1.2-0 maps_3.4.0 ape_5.6-2 lme4_1.1-31 Matrix_1.5-1
> [11] TMB_1.9.1 glmmTMB_1.1.5.9000 remotes_2.4.2

Comment: There's probably a typo in your variable name: `referecen_id` - maybe that's all there is to the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- (First error, "Error in Matrix::rankMatrix") This is a consequence of the addition of a check of the rank of the fixed-effects matrix in recent versions of `glmmTMB`.  For now, adding

```r
control = glmmTMB::glmmTMBControl(rank_check = "skip")
```

to your `phylo_glmmTMB` call should work around the problem.

- (Second error, "Error in getParameterOrder(data, parameters, new.env(), DLL = DLL) ...") I just updated the `refactor` branch to handle this problem [caused by internal changes in `glmmTMB`]. Use `remotes::install_github("wzmli/phyloglmm/pkg@refactor")` to install this version, then try your example again.

Comment: It worked, thanks @benbolker. But now I am getting another set of errors:
Error in getParameterOrder(data, parameters, new.env(), DLL = DLL) : 
  Error when reading the variable: 'psi'. Please check data and parameters.
In addition: Warning message:
In getParameterOrder(data, parameters, new.env(), DLL = DLL) :
  Expected object. Got NULL.
Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: @Non_Praying_Mantis did you manage to get around it? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Rheum_Glutinosa: are you reading in a model fitted with an older version of glmmTMB? If so, try running the `up2date()` function on your object. If not, or if that doesn't work, please post a new question. (You could also post this on the glmmTMB issues list if you prefer.)

Comment: @BenBolker no, I need to fit a new model. Can this be because I am using CRAN version of glmmTMB? Because I am not able to install the github version for some reason.

Comment: Please post a new question with all of the required info (versions of TMB and glmmTMB, whether you got any other warning messages, why you had difficulty installing the development version [i.e. what errors/symptoms], etc.)

Comment: well, this is a bit stupid but rebooting the laptop did the trick... With the "control = glmmTMB::glmmTMBControl(rank_check = "skip")" within phylo_glmmTMB I can build new models now